# numpy's loadtxt gives error converting to int when string contains decimal

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having trouble trying to load a txt file into a structured array.

Here's a simple example showing the problem.

This works fine:

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO 

in1 = StringIO("123 456 789\n231 543 876")
a = np.loadtxt(in1, dtype=[('x', "int"), ('y', "int"), ('z', "int")])

####output
array([(123, 456, 789), (231, 543, 876)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8'), ('z', '<i8')])
```

But when one of the fields contains a decimal I get an error trying to convert it to an int:

```
in2 = StringIO("123 456 789\n231 543.0 876")
a = np.loadtxt(in2, dtype=[('x', "int"), ('y', "int"), ('z', "int")])

####error
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '543.0'
```

I want python to be able to convert a number like "543.0" into 543 without throwing an error.

If it was just a single number I could use something like

```
int(float("543.0"))
```

But can I do this in combination with numpy's loadtxt?

In practice, the file I'm trying to read is about 2Gigs, and has a complicated dtype of length 37 containing a mixture of floats, strings, and ints.

I've tried numpy.genfromtxt, which seems to work for smaller files, but it eats up too much memory on the 2gig file.

Another option I've considered is to truncate all the numbers that end in ".0" with sed, which will work, but is more of a hack than a real solution.

Is there a more pythonic approach?

**Answered** (thanks Zhenya)...

```
dtypeTmp = np.dtype([(d[0], "<f8") if d[1] == "<i8" else d for d in dtype1.descr])
events = np.loadtxt("file.txt", dtype=dtypeTmp)
events.astype(dtype1)
```

Comment: Why you don't want to read them as floats, and truncate after the fact?

Comment: I think the same. However, I copied your code and run it and got integers in return in both cases.

Comment: I've loaded similar files in the past with np.loadtxt("file.txt", dtype=dtype1).  This single line of code works perfectly, except in the case when the integers in the file end with a ".0".  I'd like a solution that doesn't involve editing the 37 elements of dtype1 by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the fields that should be integers, you could use a converter that does `int(float(fieldval))`.  The following shows one way you could create the `loadtxt` `converters` argument programmatically, based on the dtype:

```
In [77]: in3 = StringIO("123.0 456 789 0.95\n231 543.0 876 0.87")

In [78]: dt = dtype([('x', "int"), ('y', "int"), ('z', "int"), ('r', "float")])

In [79]: converters = dict((k, lambda s: int(float(s))) for k in range(len(dt)) if np.issubdtype(dt[k], np.integer))

In [80]: converters
Out[80]: 
{0: <function __main__.<lambda>>,
 1: <function __main__.<lambda>>,
 2: <function __main__.<lambda>>}

In [81]: a = np.loadtxt(in3, dtype=dt, converters=converters)

In [82]: a
Out[82]: 
array([(123, 456, 789, 0.95), (231, 543, 876, 0.87)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8'), ('z', '<i8'), ('r', '<f8')])
```

Even with this, you might still run into performance or memory problems when using `loadtxt` on a 2 gig file.  Have you looked into `pandas`?  Its csv reader is much faster than the readers in numpy.

Comment: Thanks for showing me another way to do it.  I'd accept both answers if it were possible.

Comment: No worries, @Zhenya's answer is fine. The only potential drawback that I see is that it will have two copies of your data in memory, but if you have plenty of RAM, that might not be an issue.

Comment: (+1) that's cool, good to know about `converters`! I nearly went a roundabout way reconstructing the desired dtype from a string --- this way is waaay better.

Answer (score 1):

No need to edit anything by hand:

```
>>> in2 = StringIO("123 456 789\n231 543.0 876")
>>> dt_temp = np.dtype([('x', "int"), ('y', "float"), ('z', "int")])
>>> a = np.loadtxt(in2, dtype=dt_temp)
>>> 
>>> dt = np.dtype([('x', "int"), ('y', "int"), ('z', "int")])
>>> b = a.astype(dt)
>>> b
array([(123, 456, 789), (231, 543, 876)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8'), ('z', '<i8')])
```

Comment: Is there a way to change all the fields in the starting dtype from  ints to floats programatically?  I like your answer, but I don't want to type out the temporary dtype manually.  My real dtype is 37 elements long, but what if it were 100?  I attempted your suggestion but got stuck trying to iterate through the existing dtype.  Is there a way to turn an existing dtype into a list so it can be more easily manipulated?

Comment: @kithpradhan Warren's answer is better, you should accept his, not mine.